# Convert MySQL result to int (C++)

Tags: mysql, c, int, average

I'm retriving a result from MySQL with from the variable row[2].
The data from this variable is int in the mysql table but I can't put this into an int variable in c++ because I get the error message

```
average.cpp:40: error: invalid conversion from char* to int
```

Line 40 is`total += row[2];`

What am I doing wrong:?

Thanks

Comment: I bit more context would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error, when you get the value it's converted to a char *, so you have to convert it back to int.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string input(row[2]);
stringstream SS(input);
int n;

SS >> n;

total+=n;
```